# La conexión con el servidor de la base de datos ha fallado por un motivo: El servidor solicitó un método de autenticación desconocido para el cliente

Tags: php, mysql

cuando intento continuar con la instalación de nagiosql, alguien sabe el motivo, he aplicado el de otros permisos cambiar publicaciones sin éxito, gracias de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Las preguntas aquí deben hacerse en Español, así que debo pedirte que por favor edites toda tu pregunta, incluyendo el título. Gracias!

Comment: Buenas ya se ha modificado, gracias por avisar

Comment: Ya he logrado solventar el error, el usuario que había creado para la BBDD no tenía los permisos correspondientes, he ejecutado lo siguiente y ha desaparecido el error. ------> alter user 'nagiosql'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by '***********';